# Subtypes of composite types

Tags: julia

I'm trying to make a vectorized version of ismatch.

```
Base.ismatch
function ismatch(vector::Vector, regex::Regex)
  [ismatch(regex, string) for string in vector]
end
```

This works, but this

```
Base.ismatch
function ismatch(vector::Vector{String}, regex::Regex)
  [ismatch(regex, string) for string in vector]
end
```

doesn't because Vector{ASCIIString} <: Vector{String} is false.

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for your results is julias invariant typing system. This means, although `ASCIIString <: String` is `true`, `Vector{ASCIIString} <: Vector{String}` is `false`.

To get around, use parametric types:

```
import Base.ismatch
function ismatch{T<:String}(vector::Vector{T}, regex::Regex)
   [ismatch(regex,string), for string in vector]
end
```